# Apply class on checkboxes collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I would like to add a class on each instance of my collection.
This is my checkboxes collection :

```
.cov-pick-row.w-row
      = f.input_field :inspiration_image_ids, 
        :collection => @inspiration_images.map {|img| [image_tag(img.image.url(:thumb)).html_safe, img.id] },
        class: 'image-cov-pick', 
       :include_blank => '(All)', 
       :multiple => true, 
       :selected => [''], as: :check_boxes
```

I would like an input like this :

```
            .cov-pick-row w-row
              .w-col.w-col-2 w-col-small-4.w-col-tiny-6
                .image-cov-pick
                  = image_tag('my_image1.jpg')
              .w-col.w-col-2 w-col-small-4.w-col-tiny-6
                .image-cov-pick
                  = image_tag('my_image2.jpg')
              ...
```

This is the output html 
[image]

So my question is : How to add this class `.w-col.w-col-2 w-col-small-4.w-col-tiny-6` above the class `image-cov-pick` for each instances ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you post your current html output also

Comment: I edit my question with the output HTML

Answer (score 0):

You are using `simple_form` form builder for forms here. You are limited here to pass class to input only.

You can't create parent divs here using input_field tag.

If you want to create such kind collection with desired html you need to modify simple_form input_field content_tag or you can create your own html and assign desired name attribute to input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand your first proposal (the one with input_field and the content_tag) can you develop please ? I would like to avoid making the form in html if possible. Adding parent `input_field` tag doesn't work because I want to apply the style on each instances

Comment: You can look here how current code is look like http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/simple_form/SimpleForm/FormBuilder:input_field you need to override it.